# how to upload profile pic for users wordpress from front end

Tags: php, wordpress, user-profile

I have tried a lot to to upload an image for each of the users in my wordpress website, I have tried a lot of plugins like user avatar,easy user image, etc but no use, all these plugins uploads user image from the dashboard. I have used profile builder to create an edit profile page but it does not have a user image upload option. Someone kindly help me.

Comment: I have done this previously with theme my login/ user photo and admin block. This means only admin can access the dashboard and the profile is accessed directly from front end for logged in user, including a photo upload. Takes a bit of messing around though.

Comment: That is the exact thing I am looking for. Can you help me?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-block-admin/ - WPADMIN BLOCK
http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-photo/ - USER PHOTO
http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/ - THEME MY LOGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this awesome plugin for uploading a local avatar that has a front end short code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/

i paired it with the front end short code for Profile Builder (http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I've used these two plugins successfully for *this very purpose* on a few sites:

**Add Local Avatar:** http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-local-avatar/
**Theme My Login:** http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

Using these two together will create an "edit profile" page with a user image upload feature using your site's current theme. It seems like Theme My Login "should work" with other avatar upload plugins like the ones you mentioned, but I do know for a fact it works with Add Local Avatar.

You also get a lot of control with custom edit profile pages (in T.M.L.), so you could even remove the other blanks and just have the Upload/Change user image option if you like. You also have the option to redirect user levels from the dashboard/admin area to your custom page just in case.

Anyway, I think these two plugins are exactly what you're needing. Good luck, hope this points you in the right direction.